# can not find symbol error on intellij run configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using Intellij for my java project. I have a module A which is build successfully using gradle. But when I run a test configuration, I get an error 'cannot find symbol' for one of the import statement to a particular class. When I open the class, I can navigate to the imported class which is present in Module B, that means, that class is visible to intellij but still gives error. I see Module B is present as Compile time dependency in the list of dependencies of module A

I have one more sub-doubt. What is the difference between building the module using 'gradle build' vs the build which gets triggered when I run intellij's run configuration. This error does not come in former but appears in later. Why?

Apologies if my question articulation is bit confusing. I had browsed through few similar questions here but could not find a satisfactory response.

Comment: Check the scope of the dependency. If it's `Provided`, it will not be visible at runtime. If it's not the case, please share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try this : from main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Module B is present as Compile time dependency for module A. The error comes as a part of compiling the code, so I never reach runtime. Not sure, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Antikhippe I have already tried invalidating cache, I have even ran gradle's clean, cleanIdea, idea tasks. Anyways the dependency is created for Module B in dependency tree of module A, so not sure where is the problem.